# How to disable phone/tablet view in the latest version of bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

How to disable phone/tablet view in the latest version of bootstrap?

All answers I've been able to find are for older versions of bootstrap that didn't seem to work now.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
.visible-lg {
  @media (max-width: @screen-phone-max) {
    .responsive-invisibility();
  }
  &.visible-xs {
    @media (max-width: @screen-phone-max) {
      .responsive-visibility();
    }    
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-tablet) and (max-width: @screen-tablet-max) {
    .responsive-invisibility();
  }
  &.visible-sm {
    @media (min-width: @screen-tablet) and (max-width: @screen-tablet-max) {
      .responsive-visibility();
    }    
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-desktop) and (max-width: @screen-desktop-max) {
    .responsive-invisibility();
  }
  &.visible-md {
    @media (min-width: @screen-desktop) and (max-width: @screen-desktop-max) {
      .responsive-visibility();
    }    
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-large-desktop) {
    .responsive-visibility();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply! But I'm wondering where I should put these lines of code in?

Comment: These media queries gives control over items. Just add min-width and give them properties you want to. You can also able and disable items on desired width.

Comment: I get it. But in which file should I paste these in? Thanks again!

Comment: In your css file.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks anyways!